# Change Webform URL

Tags: 7, webforms

I had successfully submitted a webform. When I click on edit, it will go to this URL "node/254/submission/929/edit". Can I change to "form_a/user_name/edit"?

Answer (score 0):

No. Using [`hook_menu_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7.x) to change the `node/%webform_menu/submission/%webform_menu_submission/edit` route would break the local task display as it would no longer be a subpath of the `node/%webform_menu/submission/%webform_menu_submission` route.

Aside from that, even if you created your own custom route that evoked the same webform callbacks, you'd have to deal with the issue that a webform/username alias combo wouldn't be enough information to map to a unique submission (webforms can have duplicate titles, users can submit multiple submissions).